# Javascript function cross reference

Tags: javascript, function

I'm starting to maintain a rather large javascript project and I'd like a function cross reference stating which source file contains which functions, and for each found function, where the function is referenced.

Does anyone know of a tool that will peruse javascript source files and provide such a cross reference?

Comment: There's always `grep`

Answer (score 0):

You could check out JSDoc3 - http://usejsdoc.org/

Also YUI Doc - http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/

Comment: They just add more work and don't appear to produce a function cross reference.